# Display Marker on Custom Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using JQuery mobile, HTML5 to develop a real time vehicle tracking application. I would like to know how to place a marker at the current location on a 'custom' map. I am using the getLocation function to get the current coordinates.

```
var mapOptions={
zoom:15
mapTypeControl: true; 
navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.navigationControl.Style.Small}mapTypeID.ROADMAP};
map=google.maps.Map(document.getElementByID("map_container"),mapOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({               
  position: coords,               
  map: map,                
  title: "You Are Here!"           
  });      
}
```

the google.maps.Map function loads a 'new' map. I would like to display the marker on a custom map.

Comment: What is the difference between a _new map_ and a _custom map_? What is `coords` and what are you expecting?

Comment: a custom map is a map that i created. it has a certain route highlighted and has markers at some points. Here is the url  https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zZJgftEmZFKs.k83MIDzCxcNQ&pli=1
The current lat long values are present in 'coords'. I Would like to display this position with a marker on 'my map'.

Answer (score 2):

you need to load the coords into a LatLng object before passing it to the marker.
eg

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
```

here `coords[0]` and `coords[1]` are float type latitudes and longitudes values.

after this pass the variable `myLatlng` inplace of `coords` in the marker.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code i used in a project:

```
function CurrentPosition(){
    getPosition(function(mylat, mylng){
        drawPosition(mylat, mylng);
    });
}

function getPosition(callback) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        callback(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }, function(){
        alert(texte['myPositionErrorAlert']);
    },{enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0});
}

function drawPosition(mylat, mylng){
    LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mylat, mylng);
    yourMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: map,
        title:"MyPosition"
    });
    yourMarker.setMap(map);
}
```

Force the CurrentPosition funcition, the getPosition() will locate your position and the drawPosition() will create the marker.